# Why was my big edit rejected?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I recently made a [substantial edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18102893) to a popular accepted answer, but it was rejected with the reason: "This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. ..."

I try to keep my rejected edits low, and I have submitted big edits before that have been rejected for similar reasons, so I paid extra attention to making sure I didn't change the original intent of the answer. (I think I do have a pretty good record currently with 28 edit suggestions approved (87%), and 4 (now 5) edit suggestions rejected.)

However, the edit was still rejected. I've reviewed my edits again, but I still don't understand why it was rejected, so I'd like to get some help understanding what I did wrong. The cynic in me says *"if a reviewer sees a wall of green and red, they are going to automatically reject it"*, but I'd like to get a second opinion.

I'll include the highlights of the edits I made, along with my reasoning. Let me know if there are any issues with it, or what I should have considered instead/in addition to.

- Fix links - The original reason why I started editing the post was because the first link pointed to the documentation page of a different class, and the second link pointed to a page with the relevant info buried half-way down (I didn't even see it, initially). I updated the first link to point to the actual `AssemblyInfo` document page, and I updated the second link to an anchored link that puts the reader right at the rules for how the numbers are auto-generated.
- General cleanup - The answer has been revised 9 times by 7 authors, not including the original author, and the post has gotten a bit incoherent. There are a number of ideas present, so I tried to break each one out and clean them up to help the reader quickly parse the information in the answer. I probably didn't need the first header text, though.
- Fix the flow of the answer - The first couple of paragraphs that deal specifically with the answer to the Question are kinda hard to read, especially with the code example right in the middle of the paragraph. I moved as much text as I could to before the code example. I removed the text about adding the AssemblyInfo class to the project since that file is automatically added when the project is created.
- Quoted relevant text from link - I added a quote from the corrected second link that explains how the numbers are generated, in case the links change and so the user doesn't have to leave the page.
- Broke out the reflection code - I made a header for the section of the answer that deals with calculating the build date at runtime. I also ran the code and included an the actual value of the result in the code example as a comment/example output.
- Added examples for the comment by ashes999 - When I was originally reading this it seemed vague, and I though that a future reader might not understand what the issue was and whether or not it would apply to them, so I added two examples with screenshots to help communicate the potential issues.

As you can see, I made a lot of changes, but I hope you can see that they all make sense (at least from my perspective). I can understand how it could be overwhelming for a reviewer, and honestly I think that's what happened, but if there is something I can change to the way I make updates I would be glad to hear it.

Comment: They rejected because you don't have a 10k reputation. :-) 
They rejected because they don't like you edit a king like software engineer's post. But, I think you've done a great thing. You'd be appreciated with many thanks if it wasn't Stackoverflow. Where headAcheOverflow occurs with new-comers.

Comment: @Toaster reaching 2k rep allows you to edit any question / answer without any confirmation needed / without going through the review queue.

Answer (score 30):

The reviewers were correct in rejecting that edit, and I would have done the same. Edits should respect the original intent and content of an answer, while improving issues with the way that content was presented.

If you find yourself adding new content in an edit, particularly as much new content as you did here, that's a sign that you might want to write your own answer. If there are only one or two things to add, a comment might also be appropriate, allowing the answerer to edit in that information if they so choose.

When you add content to an existing, upvoted answer, you're calling on reviewers to trust that said content is correct. I've seen many such edits that weren't, and that would have poisoned a good answer and used its voted position to spread that incorrect information. It's often best to present that as a new answer or a comment to allow people to vote on it independently.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but this doesn't add much clarity for me other than to confirm "don't make big edits". Is the whole thing rejected because I changed too much text, or is there one particular edit I made that ruined the whole thing? Of the highlights I listed, which ones should I have not put in? "Fix links" and "Quoted relevant text from link" are good edits at least, right? "Fix the flow of the answer" only deals with the first two or three paragraphs, does my re-wording make that section less readable?